# Pass some props from parent to grangchild component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a component and I want to check its children and if the child is a specific component, I want to set some other props definations on it like this:

```
import React from 'react'

function RadioOption(props) {
  return (
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value={props.value} name={props.name} />
      {props.label}
    </label>
  )
}

function renderChildren(props) {
  return React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
    if (child.type === RadioOption)
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        name: props.name
      })
    else
      return child
  })
}

function RadioGroup(props) {
  return (
    <div class="radio-group">
      {renderChildren(props)}
    </div>
  )
}

function WhereImUsingRadioGroups() {
  return (
    <RadioGroup name="blizzard-games">
      <RadioOption label="Warcraft 2" value="wc2" />
      <RadioOption label="Warcraft 3" value="wc3" />
      <RadioOption label="Starcraft 1" value="sc1" />
      <RadioOption label="Starcraft 2" value="sc2" />
    </RadioGroup>
  )
}
```

In this example all is well but when  I want to put the child in a wrapper, I can not check it. I can just access the wrapper.

```
  ..

<RadioGroup name="blizzard-games">
  <span className="wrapper"><RadioOption label="Warcraft 2" value="wc2" /></span>
  <RadioOption label="Warcraft 3" value="wc3" />
  <RadioOption label="Starcraft 1" value="sc1" />
  <RadioOption label="Starcraft 2" value="sc2" />
</RadioGroup>
..
```

I want to check child of wrapper, well. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Perhaps your RadioOption component could handle conditionally rendering its label inside of a wrapper. That would give you single descendant that has access to all props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in this link :

https://medium.com/@skwee357/the-land-of-undocumented-react-js-the-context-99b3f931ff73

Thanks of it, I solved the problem. With context, I can pass props from parent to grandchild now.

The Example in the page:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Grandparent>
        { function() {
          return (<Parent>
            <Child/>
          </Parent>)
        }}
      </Grandparent>
    );
  }
});
var Grandparent = React.createClass({  
  childContextTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  getChildContext: function() {
    return {name: 'Jack'};
  },

  render: function() {
    var children = this.props.children;
    children = children();
    return children;
  }

});
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
});
var Child = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>My name is {this.context.name}</div>;
  }
});
React.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

Comment: React doesn't encourage you to use context, see docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html . Check this answer , it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797093/how-to-user-ajax-data-in-grandchild-component-reactjs/44797272#44797272

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes I know, but I dont know but I could not access child from parent, and there are could be lots of children.  I can use only `{this.props.children}` in parent so I cant pass props via attrs.